# Extracting numpy array from Tensorflow-Hub Module (tensor to numpy conversion)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to get started with Tensorflow-Hub to extract feature vectors from images. However, I'm not sure how one is meant to convert Tensorflow-Hub outputs (Tensors) to numpy vectors. Here's a simple example:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

im = load_img('sample.png')
im = np.expand_dims(im.resize((299,299)), 0)

module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/1")
out = module(im)

o = np.add(out, 0)
type(o)
```

The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/basics) indicate that "NumPy operations automatically convert Tensors to NumPy ndarrays", but my `np.add()` call above returns object type `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor`. Does anyone know how I can obtain a numpy array from `out`? Any pointers would be appreciated!

**Versions**:

```
# output from `pip freeze | grep tensorflow`
tensorflow==1.14.0
tensorflow-estimator==1.14.0
tensorflow-hub==0.1.1
tensorflow-probability==0.6.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work. But I did not check if the output is meaningful. But it is returning consistent results over multiple runs.

```
im = load_img('sample.png')
im = np.expand_dims(im.resize((299,299)), 0)

module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/1")

out = module(im)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  o = sess.run(out)
  o = np.add(o, 0)
  print(type(o))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
out.numpy()

type(out)  
# <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>

type(out.numpy()
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```